# mkv video from raw png pictures16 bit depth using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png, raw

I need to receive video with this output

> Stream #0:1(eng): Video: rawvideo (b16g / 0x67363162), gray16be,
> 640x576, SAR 1:1 DAR 10:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
> (default)
>
> private data:
>
> size 40(FourCC: 0x62313667 "b16g")

I am trying to use:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i depth%d.png -c:v rawvideo -vtag b16g -pix_fmt gray16be -r 30 -allow_raw_vfw 1 depth_out.mkv
```

but i received video with those parametres:

> Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, rgb555le, 640x576, SAR 1:1 DAR 10:9, 30
> fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
>
> and with this private codec data:
>
> size 40(FourCC: 0x00000000 "????": Uncompressed)

I would appreciate any advice or guesses, thanks!

*update - full log:

> ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i depth\depth%04d.png -c:v rawvideo -vtag b16g -pix_fmt gray16be -allow_raw_vfw 1 out_video.mkv ffmpeg version n4.3.1-221-gd08bcbffff Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
> built with gcc 9.3-win32 (GCC) 20200320   configuration:
> --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libxml2 --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-opencl --enable-libvmaf --disable-vulkan --enable-libvorbis --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-avisynth --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --disable-libglslang --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libmfx --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-libs=-lgomp   libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100   libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100   libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100   libavdevice    58. 10.100 /
> 58. 10.100   libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100   libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100   libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100   libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100 Input #0, image2, from
> 'depth\depth%04d.png':   Duration: 00:00:25.90, start: 0.000000,
> bitrate: N/A
>
> Stream #0:0: Video: png, gray16be(pc), 640x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 10:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
>
> Stream mapping:   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> rawvideo
> (native)) Press [q] to stop, [?] for help [matroska @
> 000001f25bb71dc0] codec rawvideo is not supported by this format
> Output #0, matroska, to 'out_video.mkv':
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
> Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, gray16be, 640x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 10:9], q=2-31, 176947 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
> Metadata:
> encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 rawvideo frame=  777 fps=602 q=-0.0 Lsize=  559475kB time=00:00:25.86 bitrate=177177.1kbits/s
> speed=  20x video:559440kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB
> global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.006204%

Comment: Use MOV: `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i depth%d.png -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16be outout.mov`, and use `-framerate 30` input option instead of `-r 30` output option to avoid 25 (default image demuxer fps) to 30 fps conversion via frame duplication.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: I am already tryed to use llogan version with .mov format and in ffmpeg it shows correct information, but when i put this file in matroska container after that without any compression with MKVtoolnix, codec ID :  V_QUICKTIME, and codec private data: 'size 86' and thats all. I need to get that file, finally, in mkv. Full log with ffmpeg mkv: Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'outout.mkv':
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, rgb555le, 640x576, SAR 1:1 DAR 10:9, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.91.100 rawvideo

Answer (score 0):

For me, splitting it into the following two steps worked:

1. `ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i .\folder\file#%05d.png -c:v rawvideo -allow_raw_vfw 1 -pix_fmt gray16be -vtag b16g depth_video.avi`
2. `& 'C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe' -o depth_video.mkv --compression 0:none --track-name "0:DEPTH" --video-tracks 0 --fourcc 0:b16g depth_video.avi`

Did not test further optimizations. Any improvements are welcome :)

**FFmpeg version**: 2023-11-05-git-44a0148fad-full_build-www.gyan.dev

**MKVToolNix version**: 80.0

**Platform**: Windows 10